# canvas.toDataURL() SecurityError - Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I read a lot of questions in stackoverflow talking about this problem, but in my case I only have this in `Internet Explorer 9+`.

I'm using the `fabric.js` library, combine with `asp.net` application. In `web.config` I had the following node:

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="PUT,POST,GET,OPTIONS"/>
      </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

**The error that I get is in the native function *`.toDataURL`***

I am 100% sure that all images have the *crossorigin="anonymous"* attribute.

If you have some doubts, please ask.
Thank you

**NOTE:**
Error as follows: *Security Error, code 18*

Comment: Internet explorer < Edge doesn't support the crossOrigin attribute.(not quite sure about 11 though)

Comment: According to http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors, known issues: _“IE11 does not appear to support CORS for images in the canvas element”_

Comment: Hi CBroe, currenclty I'm using the IE11. And the link that you provide, says that only the 4.3 Android browser doen't suport CORS